# Como passar string como parâmetro em C++

Tags: c++

Opa, pessoal, tranquilo?

Seguinte, professor de programação passou um projetinho e estou precisando passar uma string como parâmetro em C++. Como faço? Já vi na internet e nenhum das formas funcionou.

Testei assim:

```
void text_to_morse(std::string *frase, int tamanho);
```

Assim:

```
void text_to_morse(string& frase, int tamanho);
```

Assim:

```
void text_to_morse(char frase[], int tamanho);
```

Assim:

```
void text_to_morse(const char* frase, int tamanho);
```

E assim:

```
void text_to_morse(const std::string &frase, int tamanho);
```

Como fazer, afinal de contas?
A função vai traduzir uma frase que o usuário digitou em código morse e salvar em um arquivo.

Comment: Qualquer uma que funcione para você. O problema não é saber qual usar, é saber o que precisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deverá fazer ao estilo c++, em que você não precisa do parâmetro tamanho, é só chamar o método size() para obter o tamanho da string. E no fim retornar a string após a conversão.

```
std::string text_to_morse(std::string frase){
     //converte a string frase
     return frase;
}
```